# Probabilistic game with numbered tags

Tags: probability

Suppose you play the following game. You have a bag of tags each with a random positive integer written on it. You start the game with a random number, of which you read the tag. You proceed to discard all the tags with a bigger integer on them and draw again. The game ends when you are left with one or more tags with the same number on them (which will be necessarily the smallest value among the ones you started with). In how many iterations can you expect this game to end? I am fine with an asymptotic estimate.

Comment: Are all the numbers different to begin with?  I imagine so, because you say that you'll be left with one tag, but it's good to be sure.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the rules, suppose the bag originally has two numbers, $1$ and $2$.  If I draw the $2$ I discard no numbers, so I draw from the two numbers again.  If I draw the $1$ the game is over.  So the expected number of draws works out $2$.

Comment: Yes, but you don't even need to be that precise, as like I said I am more interested in the asymptotic behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of genererality, the numbers are $1,2,3\dots$.

Let $E(n)$ be the expected number of draws if there are $n$ numbers in the bag.  Obviously, $E(1)=0.$  Suppose there are $n$ numbers in the bag.  Then $$E(n)=1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nE(k)$$ since we have to draw one number, and the probability of drawing each number in the bag is $\frac1n.$  Then $${n-1\over n}E(n)= 1 + \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E(k)$$  So that$$
\begin{align}E(n)&= {n\over n-1}+{1\over n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E(k)\\&={n\over n-1}+E(n-1)-1\\&={1\over n-1}+E(n-1)\end{align}$$

From the initial conditions we get $E(n)=1+H_{n-1},$ where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

Comment: Hi. I assume that if real numbers were printed on the tags nothing would change as long as there is a finite number of tags, as you could just relabel them with integers.

Comment: @Karl  All that matters is which number is the greatest,, second-largest, and so on, so just relabel them with integers.

Comment: One question: do you think the solution would change significantly if you allowed multiple tags to share the same value?

Comment: @Karl You wouldn't get a simple answer like this.  You could proceed as in this solution, computing $E(n)$ from $E(n-1)$ (I think) but it would get very complicated.  I think you would have to settle for numerical solution.

Comment: But would there be a line of reasoning that allows me to say that it cannot be much more than $O(\log(n)$? Basically my whole aim is to see that the number of steps is roughly logarithmic in $n$.

Comment: Offhand, I have no idea.  You should probably make this another question.